# Issue with OpenGL module: Python 3.7.3

Tags: windows, command-line, python

I am trying to use a Youtube guide to create 3d shapes in Python.

The Issue is with these line:

```
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *
from OpenGL.GL import *
from OpenGL.GLU import *
```

I know the issue is with not correctly importing the OpenGL module.  At first I had an issue with importing pygame correctly.  Pycharm seemed to be able to help with that as I just click the error message and it prompted me to install it.

For OpenGL import I get the error:

```
from OpenGL.GL import *
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'OpenGL'
```

Here is what I have done.  I've looked around the web and tried to find some solutions the first one that didn't work was easy_install. I went into my python37/Scripts folder and there isn't any easy_install folder.  So I went into cmd and wrote this command: **easy_install-3.7.exe pyopengl** and got this code:

```
Searching for pyopengl
Best match: pyopengl 3.1.3b2
Processing pyopengl-3.1.3b2-py3.7.egg
pyopengl 3.1.3b2 is already the active version in easy-install.pth

Using c:\users\mp3bl\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\pyopengl-3.1.3b2-py3.7.egg
Processing dependencies for pyopengl
Finished processing dependencies for pyopengl
```

Notice is says: **pyopengl 3.1.3b2 is already the active version**.  So what does that mean?

Command: **pip install pyopengl** gave me this:

```
Requirement already satisfied: pyopengl in c:\users\mp3bl\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages (3.1.0)
```

This is my pip freeze data:

```
cachetools==3.1.1
certifi==2019.6.16
chardet==3.0.4
google-api-core==1.12.0
google-auth==1.6.3
google-cloud-core==1.0.2
google-cloud-datastore==1.8.0
googleapis-common-protos==1.6.0
grpcio==1.21.1
idna==2.8
protobuf==3.8.0
pyasn1==0.4.5
pyasn1-modules==0.2.5
pygame==1.9.6
PyOpenGL==3.1.0
pytz==2019.1
requests==2.22.0
rsa==4.0
six==1.12.0
urllib3==1.25.3
```

Whats the issue with importing the OpenGL module?

Comment: Enter this into a command prompt: python -c "import OpenGL". Do you still get a ModuleNotFoundError exception? If you got not output, then I think PyCharm is using a different Python interpreter to the one in your PATH.

Comment: My path is in appdata/local/programs/python37-32/Scripts. How do I know what path pycharm is using?  Because I do have another python27 folder in program files.

Comment: "How do I know what path pycharm is using?" See: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/status-bar.html#python-interpreter-widget. Try to install PyOpenGL as per: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/installing-uninstalling-and-upgrading-packages.html. If PyOpenGL is not in the list, you need to specify a custom repository. The instructions are on the same page. Use https://pypi.org/simple/

Comment: Hey man the command line thing didn't work, but This is beautiful.  Thank you so much for the help.  I got it working by downloading pyOpenGl in the interpreter list.